# Drupal, how to Remove Login or comment link from webform pages?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I want to remove the `Login or register to post comments` text from the page where I created a webform; is there any suggestion as to how can i use `hook_link_alter()` with this?

Comment: thanks clive i was not aware about it......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code resides in comment.module file under the theme_comment_post_forbidden() function.

If you are using Drupal 7, you may use [hook_node_view_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_view_alter/7) or [hook_entity_view_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_entity_view_alter/7) to modify the displayed content.

```
function foo_node_view_alter (&$build) {

  if ($build['#node']->type == 'webform') {
    // remove login or register to post comments
    unset($build['links']['comment']['#links']['comment_forbidden']);
    // remove add comments
    unset($build['links']['comment']['#links']['comment_add']);
  }

}
```

In case you want to use hook_link_alter in Drupal 6, use this code in your custom module

```
function comment_link_alter (&$links, $node) {

  if ($node->type == 'webform') {
    // remove register or login to post comments
    unset($links['comment_forbidden']);
    // remove add a comment
    unset($links['comment_add']);
  }

}
```

Comment: This answer is obsolete for Drupal 8

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with a content type, you could over-ride the theme.

1. copy the template file '/modules/node/node.tpl.php' into your theme's 'templates' directory
2. rename the file, calling it 'node--NODETYPE-tpl.php' (that's two hyphens after 'node'). For example, 'node--book-tpl.php' for a 'book' content type.
3. comment out the final two lines (or delete them):

   ```
   // print render($content['links']);
   // print render($content['comments']);
   ```